# I need help identifying SMD component

Tags: identification, components, surface-mount

Can anyone help identify the circled SMD chip pictured?

[image]

I have a similar chip that is damaged on a Toshiba Satellite C655 board and wanted to attempt a repair. I am new to this so any assistance would be grateful.

Comment: The [suggestion of it being an AM3423P](https://www.badcaps.net/forum/showthread.php?p=1154059) is consistent with the pinout visible on the PCB.

Comment: ... and the component designation of Q40 (Q is for transistors). Check for a short circuit after removing it, as it could have failed because of, say, a shorted capacitor.